# Error while displaying image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, computer-vision

This is the program i am trying but 3 errors are coming in 17th line which consist imread. i searched everywhere but i am not founding why it is showing this errors?
Errors are:

" : undeclared identifier

missing ) before string

syntax error )

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(‪"C:/Users/jai guru umesh/Desktop/6.jpg",0);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know where you get your open bracket there -     `...imread(‪"C:/Us...` but you need replace it with normal bracket!

Comment: i didn't get you... what you are saying..??

Comment: DON'T copy code, write it himself. Replace sign "(‪" after imread  for normal "(". Because you copied unicode.